# Laravel On-Demand Notifcations

Tags: laravel, email

Hello I am new to laravel and been practicing how to send email, sending email works using a contact form on my site but I want to send notification to the one that use my contact form using their email that they input in my contact form, I am using the on-demand notification but as I was testing it I am not recieving any notifications on my email.

My ContactController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Notification;
use App\Notifications\StatusUpdate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail
use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\NewContactRequest;

// use App\Mail\NewResponseRequest;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function show ()
    {
        return view ('home');
    }

    public function mail (ContactRequest $request)
    {
       
        Mail::to('dreadlord12318@gmail.com')->send(new NewContactRequest($request));
        // Mail::to('realityhub21@gmail.com')->send(new NewResponseRequest($request));

        // return back()->with('status','Message Received');
        return back()->with('status','Message Received');

        session()->put('error', 'There was a failure while sending the message!');

        return redirect()->back()->withInput();

        // !Notify 

        Notification::route('mail','realityhub21@gmail.com')->notify(new StatusUpdate);

    }

}
```

This is where my contactrequest where I set my mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewContactRequest extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    public $request;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->job = $request['team'];
        $this->email = $request['emailaddress'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
     
        return $this
                    ->replyTo($this->email)
                    ->view('emails.new-contact')
                    ->subject('Job Application - '. $this->job);
        // return $this->from('dreadlord12318@gmail.com')->subject('Looking for Work')->view('email_template')->with('request', $this->request);
    }
}
```

The mail::to function is working properly but the notifications::route is not sending me notifications emails. I did not change anything on my notifications file.

This my mail.php config hasn't change anything since I just set up my mail on the .env file and since the mail::to function is working perfectly fine except the notifications that I just add

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Is your SMTP setup correctly? Try catching any exceptions and check the logs.

Comment: @Qumber I did not set up my mail on the mail.php but I set it up on my .env file and it is working fine even after I added the notification::route function but the thing is the notification isn't sending anything to my one of my set emails but the mail::to is sending to my seperate email

Comment: You have a `return` before `Notification`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier that is why the function wasn't run, Thanks a lot man